# AttributeError: module object has no attribute "Series". Code works in iPython

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, ipython, python-import

Submodules aren't *implicitly* imported, and must be *explicitly* declared, but I'm making an *explicit* call to the `pd.Series` submodule, aren't I?

Regardless, shouldn't `import pandas as pd` allow for `pd.Series` to be called? The following code works flawlessly in **iPython**, but fails when executed from a script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env/python2.7
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

counts = pd.Series([632, 1638, 569, 115], index=["Firmicutes", "Proteobacteria", "Actinobacteria", "Bacteroidetes"])
```

Results in:

```
tyler@machine ~/src/stats $ python pandas.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pandas.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "/home/tyler/src/stats/pandas.py", line 6, in <module>
    counts = pd.Series([632, 1638, 569, 115], index=["Firmicutes", "Proteobacteria", "Actinobacteria", "Bacteroidetes"])
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Series'
```

Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The issue is that you've called your module `pandas`. Call it something else. And don't forget to delete the `pandas.pyc` generated on `import pandas` or else it will keep failing.

Comment: Note that this only seems to be a problem in Python 2.7.x not in 3.x.

Answer (score 0):

series in ipython not python

```
try 

  $ ipython
  import pandas as pd
  import numpy as np

  counts = pd.Series([632, 1638, 569, 115], index=["Firmicutes", "Proteobacteria", "Actinobacteria", "Bacteroidetes"])
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Code only answers are helpful but adding an explanation will help even more.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the error message `'module' object has no attribute '_tseries'`, I have missed to install `python-dateutil` package.

**The solution:**

With **python2.6**, to install pandas 0.6.1, you have to install numpy 1.6.1 and python-dateutil like 2.6.1:

```
pip install numpy==1.6.1
pip install python-dateutil==2.6.1
pip install --force-reinstall pandas==0.6.1
```