# Build SQL query string using IN with a python list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter

I built a list of values of interest in pandas.

```
table1 = pd.read_csv("logswithIPs.csv")
cips = data_dash['ip'].unique().tolist()
print(cips[:10])
['111.111.111.111', '123.123.123.123', '122.122.122.122', '2.2.2.2', '3.3.3.3', '4.4.4.4', '5.5.5.5'...'']
```

Now that I have the list above I want to see if those IPs exist in a table in my SQL Database.

```
filterIPs = pd.read_sql("select count(*) as count, url from "+table2+" where c_ip in "+cips+" group by url",conn)
```

Specifically my problem is in my syntax here `c_ip in "+cips+"`:

```
TypeError: Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly
```

How can I properly include the list in my SQL query?

***EDIT

So I finally got it to work it looks like pandas doesnt want a list it wants a string.

So I
`cipTup = tuple(cips)`. 
Then in my query I did ..

```
where c_ip in "+str(cipTup)"
```

and it worked.

My guess is that pandas knows how to treat a string like that as a list.?

Comment: This question is more about how to include a list in an SQL query built with python. The fact that you're using pandas is orthogonal to the problem you've encountered.

Comment: yah you're right.

Comment: ok I dont know why this worked .. but it did. I converted the list to tuple, like cipTup = tuple(cips). Then in my query I did .. where c_ip in "+str(cipTup)" and it worked.

Comment: print out the query string and see why

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would export/save `data_dash['ip'].unique()` as an SQL table, so that it could be efficiently used for subqueries:

```
pd.DataFrame({'ip':data_dash['ip'].unique()}).to_sql('tmp_ip', conn, if_exists='replace')
```

now you can use it on the SQL DB side:

```
qry = """
select count(*) as count, url
from tab_name
where c_ip in (select ip from tmp_ip)
group by url
"""

filterIPs = pd.read_sql(qry, conn)
```

Comment: Oh, this is a fantastic idea!

Comment: certainly more secure

Comment: Do I need to have an additional module for this? I get AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'to_frame'

Comment: @chowpay `unique()` returns an array, not a series (common mistake). So if you wrap it in a series, it should work (see the edit)

Comment: When I try to wrap it in a series I get this error , but the solution here didnt work for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18295314/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-series-code-works-in-ipython

Comment: @chowpay Check your desktop or your current directory. You'll find a pandas.pyc file there. Delete it.