# How do I make inner join with external joiner on sql in python in efficient way

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe, sqlalchemy

I want to merge an excel file with sql in pandas, here's my code

```
import pandas as pd
import pymysql
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
data1 = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')
engine = create_engine('...cloudprovider.com/...')
data2 = pd.read_sql_query("select id, column3, column4 from customer", engine)
data = data1.merge(data2, on='id', how='left')
```

It works, just to make it clearer

If input `data1.columns` the output `Index(['id', 'column1', 'column2'], dtype='object')`

If input `data2.columns` the output `Index(['id', 'column3', 'column4'], dtype='object')`

If input `data.columns` the output `Index(['id', 'column1', 'column2', 'column3', 'column4'], dtype='object')`

Since the `data2` getting bigger, I can't query entirely, so I want to query `data2` with `id` that exist on `data1`. How suppose I do this?

Comment: If `data1['id']` is large (thousands of ids), you might find the solution from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48392311/build-sql-query-string-using-in-with-a-python-list efficient. It'll allow you to use proper joins, in addition to IN operator queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could leverage the fact that SQLAlchemy is a great query builder. Either reflect the *customer* table, or build the [metadata](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html) by hand:

```
from sqlalchemy import MetaData, select

metadata = MetaData()
metadata.reflect(engine, only=['customer'])
customer = metadata.tables['customer']
```

and [build your query](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#selecting), letting SQLAlchemy worry about proper usage of placeholders, data conversion etc. You're looking for *customer* rows where id is in the set of ids from *data1*, achieved in SQL with the [IN operator](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnElement.in_):

```
query = select([customer.c.id,
                customer.c.column3,
                customer.c.column4]).\
    where(customer.c.id.in_(data1['id']))

data2 = pd.read_sql_query(query, engine)
```

If you wish to keep on using SQL strings manually, you could build a parameterized query as such:

```
placeholders = ','.join(['%s'] * data1['id'].count())
# Note that you're not formatting the actual values here, but placeholders
query = f"SELECT id, column3, column4 FROM customer WHERE id IN ({placeholders})"
data2 = pd.read_sql_query(query, engine, params=data1['id'])
```

In general it is beneficial to learn to use placeholders instead of mixing SQL and values by formatting/concatenating strings, as it may expose you to SQL injection, if handling user generated data. Usually you'd write required placeholders in the query string directly, but some string building is required, if you have a variable amount of parameters<sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1</sup>: Some DB-API drivers, such as [psycopg2](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#adapt-tuple), allow passing tuples and lists as scalar values and know how to construct suitable SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looking into a condition as WHERE IN [Some_List]. This should work for you

```
id_list = data1['id'].tolist()
your_query = "select id, column3, column4 from customer where id in "+tuple(id_list)
data2 = pd.read_sql_query(your_query , engine)
```

Hope it works.