# Python running SQL query With WHERE IN {list} and list is too long

Tags: python, sql, list, pandas

Here is a part of my script :

```
sql1 = """
                    SELECT distinct th.name, 'MMS' as Status
                    FROM t1 
                    JOIN t2 on t1.id = t2.tid
                    WHERE t2.station= 'MatS'
                    AND t1.name IN ({listthinglist})
        """.format(listthinglist=', '.join("'" + item + "'" for item in list_of_things))
    cur.execute(sql1)
```

The `list_of_things` contains 22016 items and I am unable to run this query in python. Is there an alternative to run queries like this in python.

Comment: What does "unable to run" mean?  Are you seeing an error message?

Comment: You could do batches and add the results every iteration

Comment: @PatrickHaugh my guess is the size of the query string is larger than the DBMS can handle.

Comment: Create a temporary table and use that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48392389/2681632. And don't use string formatting for passing values to SQL queries.

Answer (score 0):

Please do not use `format` for this. The `execute` function accepts a 'parameters' argument that you would pass your list to. You can modify it like so:

```
sql1 = """
  SELECT distinct th.name, 'MMS' as Status
  FROM t1 
  JOIN t2 on t1.id = t2.tid
  WHERE t2.station= 'MatS'
  AND t1.name IN (%s)
"""
cur.execute(sql1, (list_of_things,))
```

Comment: Won't this still execute an insanely sized query string?

Comment: Try it and if it produces and error, post the exact error message.

Comment: That's not my job, that's either yours, or OP's. I asked you since you posted the answer, you should know what it does.

Comment: I know what it does, but cant possibly know how it runs on OPs particular server.

Comment: Not refuting that, but you'd know whether it inserts the parameters into the string or executes them in some other way, wouldn't you? That's what I was asking. I'm not an sql guy, I'm a pandas guy.

Comment: My point is that, regardless of the fact that this is certainly better than what OP is currently doing, if it still builds a query string internally, it won't solve OP's problem.

Comment: It passes them as parameters. The dbapi, which this uses, is not simply doing a string interpolation.

Comment: Okay, that's all I was asking. Genuine question ;-)